# IAsyncEnumerable with SqlDataReader and cancellation token hangs on cancel

Tags: c#, .net-core, ado.net, .net-core-3.0, iasyncenumerable

I was trying to test out the new IAsyncEnumerable feature in c# 8(as well as the .NET Core 3 WinForm preview) but everything seems to bind up when I try to cancel the task. Pausing the debugger on the `reader.ReadAsync` while loop then continuing causes everything to play nicely. Adding a `Thread.Sleep(0)` just before the `while` also seems to help sometimes, but not consistently.

I had tried peppering `.ConfigureAwait(false)` around liberally to see if that would help but it didn't.

Is there anything wrong with my code or does SqlClient.* just not place nicely with async enumeration yet?

```cs
    private async IAsyncEnumerable<IDataRecord> SearchUIDataAsync(string searchTerm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(Queries.UIDataSearch, con) {
            CommandTimeout = 0
        };

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchTerm", searchTerm);
        await con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);

        using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        while (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            yield return reader;
        }
    }
```

This code is called form a WinForm button click event like this

```cs
if (queryRunning)
{
    cts.Cancel();
    return;
}

try
{
    await foreach (var dr in SearchUIDataAsync(formDataSearchTerm.Text, cts.Token).WithCancellation(cts.Token))
    {
        //...
    }
}
catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
```

For context `cts` is a `CancellationTokenSource` field on the form

Comment: I am not 100% sure but for additional context it had appeared that handling `TaskCanceledException`s inside of my `SearchUIDataAsync` method resolved the deadlock.

Comment: I had the same issue in .NET Core 3.1. I have discovered that I had an exception in the body of loop cycle in the generator method. Visual Studio did not raise an exception, I thought it was a deadlock.